# Error in updating data in code igniter model

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

this is model function

```
<?php
class change_data extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function change($id,$action)
    {
        if($action==0)
        $st=1;
        else
        $st=0;
        $data = array('gud_status' => $st);
        $where = "id=".$id; 
        $this->db->update_string('gallery', $data, $where);

        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }

}
```

everything is working fine.. also getting 2 parameter values but table updation fails.. affect 0 rows!!!

any body can sort this!!

Comment: is you try your query in phpmyadmin is your query work fine?

Comment: yes its working fine in phpmyadmin.. is there any way to print mysql query errors in code igniter

Comment: use this for print query echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;

Comment: use this for last execute query `echo $this->db->last_query();die;`

Comment: checked but its prints nothing

Comment: Try to check with $this->db->update('gallery', $data, "id=" . $id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass where condition in array. Ex-

```
function change($id,$action)
{
    if($action==0)
    $st=1;
    else
    $st=0;
    $data = array('gud_status' => $st);
    $where = array('id'=>$id); 
    $this->db->update_string('gallery', $data, $where);

    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```